# Looking for electric vehicle charging station time series data

Tags: data-request, time-series, energy

I am looking for time series of the electrical output of an electric vehicle charging station per hour, along with the number of electric vehicles that arrive at that charging station per hour.

Is there any available?

Comment: this dataset from Ireland has some charger availability as a timeseries, but I don't know if that can be used to approximate electrical output: https://github.com/slimtomatillo/irish_EV_charger_status